# How can I make my .factory return the result on a promise (.then)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this factory:

I'm basically trying to get a file to my server. And when I finish uploading it, I want it to return an answer.

```
    .factory('fileUpload', function($http) 
    {

        var ofileUpload = {};

        ofileUpload.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl)
        {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);
            return $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
            })
            ,function(){
                ofileUpload.answer="success";
                ofileUpload.respuesta;

            },function(){
               ofileUpload.answer="failure";
               ofileUpload.answer;
            };
        }

        return ofileUpload;
    })
```

In my controller I am trying to do this:

```
  //I am executting this:
  fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl).then(function(){
    console.log(fileUpload.answer)
  });
```

but this error appears to me.

`TypeError: fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(...).then is not a function`

How can I have my .factory return the response on a promise to receive the value returned (`ofileUpload.answer`) in my controller?

Comment: Not sure what's going on here: `return $http.post(uploadUrl, fd) {...})`

Comment: What's going on at this line: `return $http.post(uploadUrl, fd) {`. What is the opening brace doing in relation to the `.post` function call? It seems the syntax is wrong.

Comment: @4castle  sorry, check again!

Comment: still not right, you have a closing bracket after `fd`

Comment: @ValLeNain again, I have updated the link

Comment: @4castle  again, I have updated the link

Comment: you're not supposed to have a closing bracket after `fd` unless your call to `$http.post` is complete (and since you want to add custom headers, I can say it is not complete). The closing bracket should be after the object where you define the headers.

Comment: @ValLeNain Yes, I do it. check my link again. sorry man. I am secure now

Comment: you're almost done. But your success and failure functions must be in a `.then()` scope.

Answer (score 1):

I solved that. thank you!

```
    .factory('fileUpload', function($http) 
    {

        var ofileUpload = {};

        ofileUpload.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl)
        {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);
            return $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
            }).then(function(data) {
                    ofileUpload.answer="success";
                },function(response) {
                    ofileUpload.answer="failure";
                });
        }

        return ofileUpload;
    })
```